# Iterate through an NSArray of different classes that implement the same protocol with a for in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method in which I instantiate an array of objects that are all derived from he same protocol. I would like to know if I can iterate through the array and then execute their common protocol method.

Pseudocode

```
NSArray *implementations = @[/*Impl1, impl2, impl3 instantiated here*/]
  for (__________ * impl in implementations){
    [impl protocolMethod]
}
```

My issue is mainly that I don't know how I would define the type of the object in that blank in the for-in loop because they are all different classes. The closest I can think of is "id" but that doesn't seem to be a valid type because I get "Pointer to a non-const type with no explicit ownership."

Comment: Did you removed the asterisk when you were using `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be something like this:

```
for (NSObject<MyProtocol>* impl in implementations)
    [impl protocolMethod]
```

or even

```
for (id<MyProtocol> impl in implementations)
    [impl protocolMethod]
```

I usually use the first form as it's a bit more compile-time safe.

Comment: I get: 
"Pointer to non-const type 'id<MyProtocol> with no explicit ownership. Selector element type '_strong id<MyProtocol> *' is not a valid object"

Comment: Edit: Never mind! It was because the protocol was declared as an NSObject, not an id. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your protocol is `P`. Then you can use `NSObject<P> *` type, like this:

```
@protocol P <NSObject>
-(void)foo;
@end

@interface A : NSObject<P>
@end

@interface B : NSObject<P>
@end

@implementation A
-(void)foo {
    NSLog(@"A");
}
@end

@implementation B
-(void)foo {
    NSLog(@"B");
}
@end
...
NSArray *a = @[[[A alloc] init], [[B alloc] init]];
for (NSObject<P> *i in a) {
    [i foo];
}
```

The above code snippet logs `A`, `B`.